# Shopify fulfillment of orders without tracking using JSON (in Javascript)

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-api

I’m trying to update an order in Shopify as fulfilled.

I’m using Javascript code.

I tried using both the order and the filfillment IDs.

Each order has multiple line items but I want to update the entire order. And the API documentation says if you update the fulfillment ID and not specify line items it will fulfill the entire order.

This is the code I’m using.

It runs and doesn’t return an error, but the order isn’t fulfilled.

(Oh, I added the output because the tools I am using requires it, but I really don’t need it)

Help….

```
    const fulfillmentOrderId = 'f_ID';
const newStatus = 'FULFILLED'; // or 'partial'

const updateFulfillmentStatus = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://******.myshopify.com/admin/api/2024-01/fulfillment_orders/${fulfillmentOrderId}.json`,
    {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Shopify-Access-Token': 's****_******'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "fulfillment_order": {
          "location_id": "123456789",
          "id": fulfillmentOrderId,
          "status": newStatus
        }
      })
    }
  );

  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data); // Handle the response as per your requirements
};

updateFulfillmentStatus();


output=updateFulfillmentStatus()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I finally managed to get to work

```
// Replace with your actual Shopify store details
const shopName = '*******';
const apiKey = '**********';
const password = 's****_*******';


// Construct the authentication string
const authString = `${apiKey}:${password}`;

// Base64 encode the authentication string
const base64Auth = Buffer.from(authString).toString('base64');


// Replace with the actual fulfillment order ID
const fulfillmentOrderId = 1234567890045;



// Construct the Shopify API endpoint
const endpoint = `https://${shopName}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-10/fulfillments.json`;

// Update parameters for the fulfillment
const updateParams = {
  fulfillment: {
    line_items_by_fulfillment_order: [
      {
        fulfillment_order_id: fulfillmentOrderId,
      },
    ],
  },
};

// In the fetch headers, use the base64-encoded authentication string
const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Basic ${base64Auth}`,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(updateParams),
});


// Parse the response
const responseData = await response.json();

// Check if the update was successful
if (responseData.errors) {
  console.error('Failed to update fulfillment:', responseData.errors);
  // Use the callback to pass the result to the next step in Zapier
  output = [{ error: 'Failed to update fulfillment' }];
} else {
  const fulfillmentId = responseData.fulfillment.id;
  console.log('Fulfillment updated successfully. ID:', fulfillmentId);
  // Use the callback to pass the result to the next step in Zapier
  output = [{ fulfillmentUpdate: 'Fulfillment updated successfully', fulfillmentId }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as fulfillment order updates like that. If you want to make a fulfillment, use the mutation fulfillmentCreateV2 where you provide the fulfillment order ID and anything else of any interest. Not sure where you got your ideas from here, but there is nothing matching in the docs far as I can tell. I have fulfilled a few million orders using fulfillmentCreateV2, so I can attest to the fact that it is simple and just works.

Comment: But that's what I thought I did. 
I'm really not sure how to proceed.
Thanks anyway

Comment: can you please share the code for this?